# Can you reference a function that's created within ngOnInit?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I was just wondering if there's any way, shape or form to reference a function that's created within ngOnInit(), or some sort of closure you can create to do so?

Basically:

```
component(){

somefunc()
//be able to call the function that's created in ngOnInit from the component via
//click event after the component renders

ngOnInit() {
    function somefunc(){ ...whatever }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not really, unless you move the function outside of ngOnInit

Comment: Right. So what about declaring an empty variable and assigning it to your function on init? I tried that and it didn't work, but it seems like it should.

Comment: Why declare an empty variable just to re-declare it as the function? Just define it as the function...are you doing currying or something requiring dynamic function creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by assigning the method to a class member property in `ngOnInit`. In the code below, I define the method as an arrow function, to make sure that `this` refers to the instance of the component in the body of the method. See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpwvg5) for a demo.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public onButtonClick: (event: Event) => void; // Member property will refer to the method

  ngOnInit() {

    let data = "And this comes from the closure!"; // Can be used inside of onButtonClick

    // Assign the method to the member property
    this.onButtonClick = (event: Event): void => {
      console.log("The button was clicked!", data);
      ...
    };

  }
}
```

The method can then be used as an event handler:

```
<button (click)="onButtonClick($event)">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Awesome answer!! The key ingredient that I was missing was the use of arrow functions for proper binding of `this`. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo syntax is a bit confusing.

You can call a created function like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  showImage = false;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.toggleImage();
  }

  toggleImage(): void {
    this.showImage = !this.showImage;
  }

}
```

You can also call it from a click event on a button like this:

```
          <button class='btn btn-primary'
                  (click)='toggleImage()'>
            Show Image
          </button>
```

Is this what you are asking?